# Codeblocks 13.12: How To Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: shared-libraries, console-application, codeblocks, dlopen

I am using Codeblocks **13.12** on Ubuntu 14.04. While I am loading my shared library using *dlopen*, I got the error

```
dlopen failed: abc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Codeblocks "Build log" shows

```
Executing: xterm -T myConsoleApp -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /home/app/myConsoleApp
```

But my libs reside on `../libx64`, so I must provide `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:../libx64` instead.

How can I do that using C::B 13.12?

Comment: I have workaround the problem by using `-Wl,-rpath,../libx64` on `"Build Options>Linker Settings>Other Linker Options"`